# Does the jazz standard "Lament" by J.J. Johnson have lyrics?

Tags: lyrics, jazz

Does the [jazz standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_standard) "[Lament](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eek-qWg5LL0)" by [J.J. Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Johnson) have lyrics? My Google searches have turned up empty.

Comment: It sure sounds like "Lament" should have lyrics, since it's in such a clear ballad style.  Still, like you, my extensive online searches turn up no mention of lyrics, not even in this one blogger's particularly thorough discussion of the song's mechanics:  http://wallacebass.com/?p=1916.  I suggest that's evidence that the song didn't have published lyrics, but it's certainly not proof.  Maybe someone needs to write some lyrics after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if J.J. Johnson himself wrote lyrics on Lament, I would say no.

On this first release of the standard, in the [Jay & Kay](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jay-Kai-Jay-Kai/release/2927218) album in 1955, there is no lyrics, and no credited singer :

> **Baritone Saxophone** – Leo Parker (tracks: A5)
>     **Bass** – Al Lucas (tracks: A5), Charlie Mingus* (tracks: A1 to A4, B1 to B4), Eddie Safranski (tracks: B5)
>     **Drums** – Kenny Clarke (tracks: A1 to A4, B1 to B4), Shadow Wilson (tracks: A5), Tiny Kahn (tracks: B5)
>     **Engineer** – Rudy Van Gelder (tracks: A1 to A4, B1 to B4)
>     **Guitar** – Billy Bauer (tracks: A2 to A4, B4)
>     **Liner Notes** – Jack McKinney
>     **Piano** – Hank Jones (tracks: A5), Lou Stein (tracks: B5), Wally Cirillo (tracks: A1, B1 to B3)
>     **Supervised By** – Ozzie Cadena (tracks: A1 to A4, B1 to B4)
>     **Trombone** – J. J. Johnson* (tracks: A1 to B4), Kai Winding (tracks: A1 to A4, B1 to B5)

The same year, [Hazel Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazel_Scott) covers the song on the piano ([Hazel Scott - Lament](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtFQEewMFkw)), but doesn't sing on it, even she's a reputed singer.

Also, I didn't find any covers with vocals.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Hendricks wrote lyrics, "Lambert, Hendricks and Ross"

Comment: Hendricks wrote lyrics to JJ Johnson melody

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVk1Qb2ix_Y
Mark Murphy - Lament

Answer (score -1):

This is a version of the tune with lyrics sung nicely by Bev Kelly; I'll try to find out who wrote them and get back here with the gen.

[Lament - Bev Kelly (Live at the Jazz Safari)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CYnIkOe4jk)